# In Elm 0.19.1, is it possible to make an http-get request within a decoder for the initial model?

Tags: elm

I have a component created in Elm where users can create a list of different criteria. For this component, users should be able to create criteria to search for contacts. These contacts will be shown on a different (non-Elm) page. If the users return to the criteria builder, the previous filled in criteria should be shown again.

To do this, I use the JSON that was used to create the query in Elm. This should be decoded to create the objects that will show the input that the user has made before.

One of the objects I use is a list. This list contains of tuples with id and name. For the query builder, I only send the id of the objects in the JSON to the back-end. This means that, if a user returns to the criteria builder, the decoder can only decode the list of id's. For my list selection, I also want to fetch the names of the objects with the id's.

Now this is where I have some problems. To make an http-request, I have to catch the result with an `Cmd.Msg`. In the update function, I must then update my Model. The problem is, I don't have a model yet, because I'm still decoding my initial model. Also, I guess using a `Decoder` (for the result of the http-request) within a `Decoder` (for my initial model) is not the best of ideas.

Is there a way to solve this problem where I am making an http-request within a `Decoder` for my initial Model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a handful of options here, depending on how complicated your situation is. At the end of the day, `init` produces a `(Model, Cmd Msg)` value, and your HTTP request(s) can be part of that `Cmd`.

Option 1: Generate HTTP requests based on the decoded model

```
init : Decode.Value -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init json =
    let
        initialRequests model =
            List.map initialRequest model.items
    in
    case Decode.decodeValue flagsDecoder json of
        Ok model ->
            ( model, initialRequests model |> Cmd.batch )

        Err _ ->
            ( initialModel, Cmd.none )
```

Option 2: Generate HTTP requests while decoding

```
init : Decode.Value -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init json =
    let
        flagsDecoder =
            Decode.map (\items -> ({ items = List.map Tuple.first items }, List.map Tuple.second items))
                (Decode.field "items" (Decode.list itemDecoder))
        itemDecoder =
            Decode.field "name" Decode.string
                |> Decode.map (\name -> (name, initialRequest name))
    in
    case Decode.decodeValue flagsDecoder json of
        Ok ( model, cmds ) ->
            ( model, cmds |> Cmd.batch )

        Err _ ->
            ( initialModel, Cmd.none )
```

Your `init` function will need to be able to return a `Model` value that is "incomple", waiting on these responses to come back. Sometimes that's as simple as modeling values that you're waiting on as `Maybe` values, sometimes you might want to wrap a large portion of your model in a value that indicates if it's valid or not.

```
type Model
    = Initializing String (Maybe Thing1) (Maybe Thing2)
    | Ready { baseUrl : String, thing1 : Thing1, thing2 : Thing2 }
```

Comment: A basic example is at https://ellie-app.com/kTt6r444nX3a1

Comment: In my case, where I want to make zero, one, or multiple http-requests when deconding the flags, I think I should go for option 2? However, I don't see making the http-request anywhere in your solution, so I assume it will be in the function "initialRequest". That again raises my question how I can handle the "Cmd Msg" output of that function. I guess I should handle that in the update function, but there I must update my Model that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes, `initialRequest` would create the GET request. That GET request will define a `Msg` value which will get sent to `update` when a response is received. Your `init` function will need to return a model that's waiting for these responses. I've added a note at the end of the question that may help.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your solution as I'm quite new to Elm (I know, this is quite a complex problem for someone just starting). I think I understand your solution. My question is, for the update-function that will handle the `cmds` from the decoder, can I ALWAYS update the model to the `Ready`-state? Or should I somehow check if there are still `Cmd`'s to execute?

Comment: If you have multiple requests, those are going to come back as multiple calls to your `update` function with their corresponding `Msg` values (it's possible to join multiple requests as `Task` values and turn them into a single `Cmd`, but that requires running the requests in sequence instead of parallel). So your `update` function will need to be able to determine if it has all that it needs to set the `model` to `Ready` or if it's waiting for more responses.

Comment: I think I now have a solution that I want to try. I will create a list of `Cmd Msg` that will be passed through all decoders. Everytime an http-request has to be made, a new `Cmd Msg` will be added to the list. When everuthing has been decoded and the list of `Cmd Msg` is not empty, it will create the `Initializing` model and execute all `Cmd Msg`'s is the list.

I think this should work. Thank you for helping and inspiring me!